# Configure Squid Proxy Server to use TCP for DNS lookups?

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, tcp, squid, openbsd

Is there a way to configure squid 3.5.1 to use TCP for DNS lookups?

I've setup up the proxy server to use TCP for lookups by adding "options tcp" to my /etc/resolv.conf, but squid seems to be doing its own thing.

Comment: How did you get the idea that `options tcp` would do anything? I see no mention of `tcp` anywhere in `man resolv.conf`, and I didn't find a single program using TCP for DNS lookups even with that option.

Comment: @kasperd you're probably a Linux user - I thought I mentioned I was on OpenBSD, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

Use your firewall to reject (not drop) UDP packets from squid.  It'll soon get the message.  I do wonder why on earth you'd want to do this, though.

Comment: It shouldn't have to "get the message" I should be able to do this using configuration.

Comment: @paxos1977 You can if you [recompile squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Dnsserver). But that doesn't answer the question of why you are trying to do this. It's a Very Bad Idea. At least, it's a bad idea if you have to handle the "The internet is slow" calls...

Comment: "Should" is a moral imperative.

Comment: @womble yes it is, I should go fix that.

Comment: @Michael Hampton that's not really your concern.

Comment: 2 close votes for off topic. How is asking a question about squid configuration off topic for a sysadmin website?

Comment: @paxos1977 Of course it's not my concern. It's your concern! I asked _solely_ in order to understand your situation better in hopes of finding a better answer for you. If you don't want to explain, then you certainly are not obligated to do so. But you're unlikely to get a good solution without doing so.

Comment: @Michael Hampton I appreciate your wanting to understand the scenario better, but it really doesn't get any clearer than as stated in the question. Can I configure squid to do this or not? The answer appears to be no.